# Execution failed due to configuration error: Host name: '<DNS ALB>' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=<mycustomdomain>)

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, aws-api-gateway, nlb

In my current AWS set up I have an API gateway - with a custom domain -> a VPC link -> NLB -> ALB -> ECS cluster.

I created a custom domain for my API gateway and added the ACM certificate, my NLB has a TCP listener ,and the ALB has an HTTPs Listener with the same cert I added for my custom domain. when I test one of the methods I created from the API gateway from the console I get the error "Execution failed due to configuration error: Host name: 'DNS of ALB' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=)".

The certificate is for .com - with an additional subject name for *..com.

I added a CNAME record that maps my subdomain to my API gateway endpoint.

When I curl d..com with verbose output I see that it does match the certificate

....

subjectAltName: host "d..com" matched cert's "*..com"
issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA.,....
SSL certificate verify ok. ....

....

However I still get an internal server error

Any idea what I have done wrong?